# SQL query for wp_links in multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I can get links from the WordPress database that are in a specific category like this (I have added line breaks to the SQL part for clarity):

```
$category1 = 'stuff';
$category2 = 'other_stuff';

$q = 'select * from wp_links l
    inner join wp_term_relationships r on l.link_id = r.object_id
    inner join wp_term_taxonomy using (term_taxonomy_id)
    inner join wp_terms using (term_id)
    where taxonomy = "link_category"
    and name = '.$category1;

$results = $wpdb->get_results($q);
```

How would I retrieve links that are in *both* `$category1` and `$category2` (I do mean *both* categories, not *either* category)?

Comment: Will this always be `2` categories, or do you need to generalise it to `n` categories?  Also, what table does `name` actually belong to?  I *presume* it's in `wp_terms`?

Comment: @Dems My specific need is for `2` categories, though I would welcome an answer for `n` for educational purposes. You are correct that `name` is in `wp_terms`--apologies for the omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that the `name` field you are searching on is in the `wp_terms` table, there are two principle options.

The first just looks for entities with the first category, then uses another join the find those that also have the second category.  This involes using the same table in two different joins, and so uses aliases and avoids the `using` keyword.

```
select * from wp_links           l
inner join wp_term_relationships r  on l.link_id          = r.object_id
inner join wp_term_taxonomy      t  on r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_terms              c1 on t.term_id          = c1.term_id
inner join wp_terms              c2 on t.term_id          = c2.term_id
where taxonomy = "link_category"
and c1.name = 'stuff'
and c2.name = 'other_stuff'
```

The alternative is much more scalable to more than just two catagories, but involves a sub-query...

```
select
  l.*
from
(
  select l.id from wp_links        l
  inner join wp_term_relationships r on l.link_id          = r.object_id
  inner join wp_term_taxonomy      t on r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
  inner join wp_terms              c on t.term_id          = c.term_id
  where taxonomy = "link_category"
  and c.name IN ('stuff', 'other_stuff')
  group by l.id
  having count(distinct c.name) = 2
)
  subquery
inner join wp_links l ON subquery.id = l.id
```

The inner query finds all that have one category or the other, but then the having clause only lets through those that have two categories in our list.  (In other words, both of them.)  *[It also assumes that the `wp_links` table as an `id` column to use as a unique identifier.]*

Comment: `wp_links` appears to use `link_id` as a unique identifier. I tested your second solution, replacing `l.id` with `l.link_id` and it appears to be working. Thanks for going the extra mile here--I'll implement your second solution to give myself some flexibility down the road.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with the OR?

```
   $q = 'select * from (select * from wp_links l
        inner join wp_term_relationships r on l.link_id = r.object_id
        inner join wp_term_taxonomy using (term_taxonomy_id)
        inner join wp_terms using (term_id)
        where taxonomy = "link_category"
        and name = '.$category1.') as t1 join (select * from wp_links l
        inner join wp_term_relationships r on l.link_id = r.object_id
        inner join wp_term_taxonomy using (term_taxonomy_id)
        inner join wp_terms using (term_id)
        where taxonomy = "link_category"
        and name = '.$category2 .') as t2
        on t1.term_id=t2.term_id;
```

I don't think this is the best solution, but you don't give me more details about your structure, tables what you have

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this will give me links that are in $category1, plus links that are in $category2. I want the overlap between the two categories.

Comment: can you display the output of your query?

Comment: Suppose $category1 = "things_that_are_red" and $category2 = "things_that_are_round". Your query will give me apple, fire truck, baseball. I want only apple, because it is red *and* round.

Comment: I would recommend you that make first a self join with the table which have the Name column to get those 2 values and after that make the rest of the joins